# Click drop down menu

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a span:

```
<span class="ToolbarLinkButton" id="ComparisonReports" onclick="function_which_shows_dropdown_menu">
```

When I click on it I get drop down menu:

```
<div id="divPopupTemplateComparisonReports">
  <div class="ToolbarButtonMenu">
    <div class="ToolbarLinkButton" id="ComparisonReportsView" onclick="some_functions">
```

But when I try to click on element (id="ComparisonReportsView"), it says that: "**Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Cannot click on element**"

```
  on(Main) do |page|
    page.spnComprReptVer_element.fire_event ("onclick")
    page.divComprReptView_element.click
    sleep 2
  end
```

And when via *fire_event* it says that step passed but nothing was executed (no menu item clicked).

```
  on(Main) do |page|
    page.spnComprReptVer_element.fire_event ("onclick")
    page.divComprReptView_element.fire_event ("onclick")
    sleep 2
  end
```

How I can click on it somehow other way, or what I can use?
[image]

Comment: Can you share your page object definition? Without it, it is difficult to know what you are trying. For example, the DOM looks to contain an iframe. Is that being accounted for in the element definition?

Comment: in_iframe(:id => 'ContentAreaFrame') do |frame|
    div(:divComprReptView, :id => 'ComparisonReportsView', :frame => frame)
  end

Comment: I suppose that div you're trying to click on is not able to get this event ('onclick'). I mean that there is a link can be inside this div and you can be able to click on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know your definition for `divComprReptView_element` but I assume it has [#when_present](http://watir.github.io/watir-webdriver/doc/Watir/Element.html#when_present-instance_method) just use it and give it a block to execute `click`(e.g. `page.divComprReptView_element.when_present.click`).

Comment: divComprReptView_element is a name of element: div(:divComprReptView, :id => 'ComparisonReportsView', :frame => frame)

Comment: Try it and it will work. Check the link I have added for `#wait_present`. It is an instance method for `Watir::Element` which is what `divComprReptView_element` is.

Comment: Wrote: NoMethodError: undefined method `wait_present' for #<Watir::Div:0x40df028>

Comment: Sorry, misspeled the method - it is `#when_present`. Fixed the answear.

Comment: `when_present` doesn't help too (